# Formatted date representation

Tags: java, android

My date is displayed in a button in this format

```
new SimpleDateFormat("EEEEEEEEEE MMMM dd yyyy")
```

i.e.

```
wednesday 15 may 2013
```

But i want to capitalised each starting element i.e.

```
Wednesday 15 May 2013
```

Comment: first char to upper case

Answer (score 2):

It'll give what you want, why is it not working at your end:

```
    Date date = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEEEEEEEE dd MMMM yyyy") ;
    System.out.println(format.format(date));
```

"Wednesday 15 May 2013"

Answer (score 1):

Four times E is enough:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE dd MMMM yyyy");
```

Where EEEE is the day of week long.

From [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)
if the number of pattern letters is 4 or more, a calendar specific long form is used

Answer (score 0):

trying with Below Way also will solve your Problem.

```
SimpleDateFormat format= new SimpleDateFormat("EEEEEEEEEE MMMM dd yyyy", Locale.US);
```